# How can I specify the default JVM arguments for programs I run from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Is there a way to specify default JVM arguments when I'm running my code from eclipse, rather than specifying the same ones over and over for each run/debug/etc configuration?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, right click the project. Click `Run as` then `Run Configurations`. You can change the parameters passed to the JVM in the `Arguments` tab in the `VM Arguments` box.

That configuration can then be used as the default when running the project.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to set a default for all projects?

Comment: I think that's done in the Java section of the main Eclipse settings.

Comment: One question, when I configure it manually like you said, Will the configuration stick with java application when we build it to war file and deploy to websphere server?

Comment: Yes, but the MUCH BETTER WAY to do it, is by following Alice's way below because it makes it permanent for every project.

Answer (score 140):

Go to Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs. Select the JRE you're using, click Edit, and there will be a line for Default VM Arguments which will apply to every execution. For instance, I use this on OS X to hide the icon from the dock, increase max memory and turn on assertions:

```
-Xmx512m -ea -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: HI, if I am running the java program from cmd, how can I specify the VM arguments? any example would do

Comment: If you open an actual window you can have an argument with a person standing outside so it makes sense to some people that the Window menu is a good place to put default VM arguments.

Comment: Best place to put common arguments for munit tests in mulesoft's Anypoint Studio. Works across all mule projects.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there is no option to create global configuration for java applications. You always create a duplicate of the configuration.

[image]

Also, if you are using PDE (for plugin development), you can create target platform using windows -> Preferences -> Plug-in development -> Target Platform. Edit has options for program/vm arguments.

Hope this helps