# Out of memory error in java arrays

Tags: java

I am using the following piece of code  in one of my methods in java:

```
int []  byte_song = new int[8414449];
int []  int_song = new int[8414449 - 45];
```

If i just write:

```
int []  byte_song = new int[8414449];
```

it does not give me any error. However if i write:

```
int []  byte_song = new int[8414449];
int []  int_song = new int[8414449 - 45];
```

it gives me `OutOfMemoryError`.

I also tried calling `System.gc();` before `int []int_song = new int[8414449 - 45];` still i get the error. Can some body please help me out in this.

Comment: System.gc() is a mere request. One cannot rely on it to free memory instantly.

Comment: So let me get this staright: it doesn't give you an error when you allocate less, but it does give an `OutOfMemoryError` when you allocate more? Yes, that is strange.

Comment: @Pavan With OP's code, even if it were a deterministic cleanup of every last available byte, it would make no difference since that code doesn't create any garbage.

Comment: Do you have any other memory consuming objects in your code?  Not neccessarily in the same method?

Comment: @ Joyson : Some math. Your code block requires atleast 8414449* 4 * 2 (assuming 45 does not play a role).  The byte_song is not eligible for any garbage collection yet

Comment: When do you get the exception if you do `int []  int_song = new int[8414449 - 45];` first, and then `int []  byte_song = new int[8414449];`?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik - Are you saying that the entire array (and not just its descriptor) is located on the stack?

Comment: Can you post a the full program and check which version of the JVM (and which platform) you are using? I created a test program with just those lines and it works fine for me.

Comment: I'm also curious if using a wrapper class `Integer` would make any difference.

Comment: @PM77-1 No. The array is on the heap, including any "descriptors" (I guess you mean array headers).

Comment: @ Joyson : It is not easy to guess the default . For reference: The default memory for Oracle JVM is dynamically determined. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html

Comment: I have a lot lenthier code in the method.Debugging the program gave me the error on the following line so i wrote a test app  with just these two lines of code and still i got the same error.The test program just contains these 2 lines of code.

Comment: I ran the code in eclipse.Using Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs i found the Type specified as  Standard VM.

Comment: BTW: For expert developers; you can use memory mapped files to store very large arrays of data.  The size of these files is only limited by the free space on the disk, not the maximum heap size.

Comment: Just for grins, trying setting `byte_song = null;` before you allocate int_song.

Answer (score 7):

You need to allocate more memory. Use the `-Xmx` [memory option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for) for this. The JVM has a default amount of memory beyond which it will not allow you to allocate any more, and it's typically less than the amount of memory you have on the computer.

Comment: yan Can u please tell me how to allocate more memory using the above -Xmx if that can help.

Comment: @Joyson :  Example java -Xmx1100m -classpath <classpath >   <fully qualified name of class>.  Why  not refer the link in the answer?

Comment: Exactly yan but cant i do this programmatically than doing it in cmd.I guesss if i m not wrong the above command has to be written in cmd.

Comment: @Joyson :  That is correct. The value has to be set when jvm starts.   It can be set in eclipse run configuration as well. Please check docs.

Comment: @Joyson : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse

Comment: Thnx yan for above link i will follow it asap

Comment: @Joyson The maximum is the actual maximum.  It's not the maximum, unless-I-change-my-mind-later maximum.  You can't change it because it is allocated on startup.

Comment: yan i tried increasing the default Vm arguments however still no luck :(