# Running program from eclipse the same way as it's run in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, arguments, buildpath

Not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

This is my local file structure:
[image]

If i run the following command from the command line in windows in the above directory: `java -jar server.jar -l SAD1.lvl -g 50 -c "java -Xmx2048m sc.SearchClient"`. Then the program executes completely as it should i.e. a GUI displays and then some computations etc.

My problem is that I want to move this to eclipse instead, so I can simply build and run my program after code edits instead of running it from the command line.
This is how my file structure looks in eclipse:

[image]

As you can see I have added the jar to the project build path. Additionally, after right clicking Assignment 1 -> Run As.. -> Run Configurations -> Arguments I have added the following arguments to the field "Program Arguments":

[image]

Yet when I run the program from eclipse I get some parts of the program (early lines in the Main method) to print some text to the console but the main GUI that shows up when I run it from the command line does not show. Also any additional text output that I get in the command line does not show either.

I'm clearly missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't been using eclipse for a long time, but from what I see, I'd say Program arguments are what they say, meaning that you should remove the `java -jar server.jar` part (assuming arguments after are used by your program and not the JVM).

Comment: I'm using the -Xmx option to specify some memory limits, so maybe that should go in the VM part actually. I'll just try and remove the part you suggested and possibly move the -Xmx part to the VM arguments.

Comment: No luck doing that. But I think you might be right in that the arguments are not specified correctly. Not sure how to get it working though

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300970/1276128)

Comment: Not really no :/ Even if I leave out the jvm memory options it should still work, which it doesn't..

Comment: The  option "-c" and its argument is meant to be processed by your application? Should it start another Java program?

Comment: @laune Yes it should start to another program called SearchClient.java where there is a main method.