# What arguments can we add to 'Generic JVM Argument' to display the GC info in RAD Websphere v7.5?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, arguments, websphere, rad

In RAD WebSphere, I want to add the some arguments to the JVM, in order to display some information about the garbage collection. I notice that this action is in the `Administration Console-->Server-->Application Server-->Server1-->Java and Process Management-->Process Definition-->Java Virtual Machine-->Generic JVM Argument`.

Normally in Oracle JDK, there are arguments that we can add like: `-Xms1000m -Xmx1000m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=500m -XX:NewSize=500m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:/home/sherpa/Sherpa/Server/log/gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`.

I tried to add these arguments in it, but it seems that it doesn't work with these arguments.

So is there some specific arguments that can only be used in RAD WebSphere? What arguments can we use in RAD?

I am looking forward to your opinions!

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Websphere application server, you'll be using the IBM JVM.

You can get additional information about garbage collection using the `-verbose:gc` option.

You can find more information about the output produced by this option on [this Knowledge Center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/diag/tools/gcpd_verbosegc.html?lang=en).

Comment: As I side note, I'm not sure what you meant by "RAD Websphere". There are two products, RAD which is an eclipse-based IDE and Websphere Application Server which is a Java application server. 

I've assumed you're using both together and want to set the garbage collection options on the JVM for Websphere application server.

Comment: I think my tool is RAD with WebSphere on it. When I look at the product information, it is: IBM Rational® Application Developer™ for WebSphere® Software.

Answer (score 1):

RAD is just your developing environment, an IDE. You can have WebSphere Application Server runtime as test environment  installed together with RAD, but it is separate server, it just happens to be already integrated in the Servers View.

So in general all rules related to WebSphere apply. WebSphere runs IBM JVM, so if you want to enable verbose gc check the WebSphere infocenter, and do not provide Oracle JVM params as they simply dont work in IBM JVM :-)

So for WebSphere you should enable it via admin console in the JVM settings page, just call it via browser, but it is available to invoke it from RAD in servers view also.

For details check:

- [Java virtual machine settings](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html?lang=en)
- [Garbage Collector options](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/commands_gc.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en) - to be specified via Generic JVM options