# How to check if JavaSE Commercial Features are enabled?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In light of the recent apparent crackdown of Oracle on Java users ([read here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/12/16/oracle_targets_java_users_non_compliance/)), I'm wary about my continued use of Oracle's JDK - or anything Oracle for that matter. The above article warns:

> “If you download Java, you get everything – and you need to make sure
>   you are installing only the components you are entitled to and you
>   need to remove the bits you aren’t using,” our anonymous expert
>   warned.

I'm only using the OracleJDK for personal use, on my personal laptop. I haven't given the code to anyone. Period.

Is there a simple way to check if I have any of the commercial features enabled? I use IntelliJ IDEA CE. I don't want to accidently activate them so I'm seeking your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

So [oracle's java BCLA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) states the following.
[image]

This means that you can pretty much do what ever you want with the software as long as you are the one using it and you arn't violating any of the later clauses such as reverse engineering / decompiling to provided software.

Now who does pay Oracle for the JDK? Well let's look at the highlighted section. `Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without license fees to reproduce and use internally the Software complete and unmodified for the sole purpose of running Programs.` The first part `non-exclusive` this means that you are not the only person granted the license. `Non-transferable` this means that you may not give your license to another person. `limited license` this means Oracle can take your license away and that you are not unlimited with your relation to the intellectual property. `without fees` Free! `to reproduce and use internally the Software complete and unmodified for the sole purpose of running Programs.` This means that you can use the jdk your self to run your java code. So if you were say a school that charged tuition and used the jdk as part of the curriculum you would owe royalties consequence of providing the jdk to external consumer (the student) as part of a package delivered for a fee.

Now it's the next part that has you worried. `THE LICENSE SET FORTH IN THIS SECTION 2 DOES NOT EXTEND TO THE COMMERCIAL FEATURES.` Digging deeper for a description of the commercial features we find [this page.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html) which includes the following portion that would have anyone a little worried.

[image]

While this may seem alarming you would have had that talk with oracle when you were downloading Java SE advanced or Java SE suit. Earlier in the page under [vanilla] Java SE it says 'Java SE can be used for free internally to run applications and may be redistributed in accordance with the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for the Java SE Platform Products (the “Java BCLA”)'

To address your initial question as to weather the commercial features are enabled or not you can look at the [vm options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse) that you are using at run-time, as this is where the [commercial addon's are enabled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/enhancements-8.html).

Do not modify the software Oracle distributes to you as the license provided to you is for use of the software 'complete and unmodified'.

Comment: thanks for that information. I checked my VM options in IntelliJ (Run>Edit Configuration) and they're empty. See [here](http://imgur.com/a/QyEQ2). The only VM option I found was in an older project which had `-XX:+UseG1GC` but this shouldn't be an issue, right? I'd assume since I didn't activate anything manually, nothing should be triggered. Thoughts?