# How to override JVM Arguments in Weblogic

Tags: java, java-8, weblogic

I want to override JVM option for odbc like adding below ;

```
-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false
```

However in Weblogic 12c and using Java 8, I don't know where should i override it from.

Refer below link, I need to override the JVM option.

[How can I specify the default JVM arguments for programs I run from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse)

Should i set in weblogic or jdk8 directory ?

Comment: @CKing It is not same.

Comment: You want to set JVM options for Weblogic?

Comment: @CKing Yes, I want to set for weblogic which is like referred link.

Comment: And the answer I linked to doesn't ring a bell (read *setDomainEnv.sh*)

Comment: @CKing There are hundreads of rows. Where should i put him ?