# can "jmx exporter" be used without compliling my spring boot Application in jar file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, jmx-exporter

In official git repository (https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter), i see i need to use this command "java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=8080:config.yaml -jar yourJar.jar
".  I am running my Spring Boot Application in my eclipse without compiling in jar format.

So how can i get the metrics from jmx exporter without compiling my spring app in jar file. Can anybody pls help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify "Run configuration" in your Eclipse IDE to include necessary JVM arguments as you shown in question (`java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=8080:config.yaml`). For details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse) on how to do it.

Jar file (`jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar`) and YAML file (`config.yaml`) has to be in current working directory, otherwise you might need to provide full path.

Comment: I am getting following output in my console after i followed the steps you told me:- "Error: Could not find or load main class java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java"I am wondering which class, java couldnt find

Comment: omit `java` from arguments. here is an [example](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/8/8a/PojoBindable_VMParameters.png)

Comment: Thanks Alot, It finally worked after i removed "java" from arguments.